# Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

какие знаки препинания необходимо поставить и пишется ли слово "что" в данном случае с большой буквы

Он задается вопросом что делать

Answer (score 1):

Если нет никаких причин отсылать читающего к работам Чернышевского и Ленина, то все просто:

***Он задался вопросом, что делать.***

Если же "Что делать?" по мысли автора - название или цитата, то

***Он задался вопросом "Что делать?"***

Последний вариант хоть и возможен, но крайне маловероятен.
Других возможностей я не вижу.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы поставил двоеточие после слова "вопрос".Он задался вопросом: что делать.

Comment: согласен. как вариант.